# How to fully delete comitted files?

Tags: git

I have a git repo with say 10-20 commits. I added some files of 1gb and commited the change.
I forgot to track these 1gb files using **git lfs**.

Now when I tried to push it to github it failed cause of the big size.
Now I want git to completely forget about this change.
So I made a copy of the repo and to undo the changes.

I did `git reset --hard hash_value` but still the size of the `.git` directory is 1gb something.

Which suggest that It knows about the change/files that were added, and still I can't push the changes.

Is there some way to tell git to completely forget about the files made in/after some specified commit (in this case the last commit made)?

Comment: The dupe is incorrect. As for the post, git push is not performed successfully yet.

Answer (score 0):

> but still the size of the .git directory is 1gb something.

If you have successfully removed the commit with the command `git reset --hard <hash_value>`, the next step is running the garbage collector for searching and deleting unreachable/unreferenced `<hash_value>`.

```
git gc --prune=now
```

> Still I can't push the changes.

You might need to force push after removing the commit

```
git push --force-with-lease
```